# Is there a way to quickly search the web via Spotlight?

Tags: keyboard, spotlight, web-browsing, search-engine, ipados

On macOS, you can use Spotlight to quickly do a web search of your query [through hotkeys](https://www.danrodney.com/mac/#spotlight) by pressing <kbd>CMD + B</kbd>.

Is there any equivalent functionality in iPadOS?

Using a Bluetooth keyboard, I have tried the same hotkey on iPadOS 13.1.2 with no luck. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing a query in Spotlight brings up the first result, but I would specifically like it to bring up a web search in Safari's default search engine.

Comment: I dont know if anything changed in ipadOS, but on iOS 12, at the bottom of spotlight, there are three options of search App Store, search web and search maps. would they be useful, or you are specifically asking for shortcuts?

Comment: @ankii Those options are still at the bottom of a Spotlight query in iPadOS 13, but I'm specifically looking for a keyboard shortcut. I'm guessing it's not currently possible, so I think I'll just submit feedback to Apple and cross my fingers.